# SharePoint 2013 Workflow Manager InvalidRequestException

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, project-server, workflow-manager

I have an on-premises SharePoint 2013 farm with Workflow Manager 1.0 installed and configured on a single server (development environment). When we go to manually execute a workflow against a list, we are presented with the standard error message ("Something went wrong. To try again, reload the page and then end the workflow").

Going into the ULS logs returns the following error message:

```
Microsoft.Workflow.Client.InvalidRequestException: The scope '/SharePoint/default/56f5f99d-c701-4c08-b3e1-d4048d883bd7/7d3631b1-5190-4a9f-ac7b-0be2da1fa8a7' has no workflows under it. HTTP headers received from the server - ActivityId: 4347c8a0-6285-4d78-80d4-fbb7bd54fc90. NodeId: NWN401WV1315. Scope: /SharePoint/default/56f5f99d-c701-4c08-b3e1-d4048d883bd7/7d3631b1-5190-4a9f-ac7b-0be2da1fa8a7. Client ActivityId : 161a609d-a1fb-d023-3c07-239728cc4929. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.    
 at Microsoft.Workflow.Common.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)    
 at Microsoft.Workflow.Client.HttpGetResponseAsyncResult`1.End(IAsyncResult result)    
 at Microsoft.Workflow.Client.ClientHelpers.SendRequest[T](HttpWebRequest request, T content)     -
 -- End of inner exception stack trace ---    
 at Microsoft.Workflow.Client.ClientHelpers.SendRequest[T](HttpWebRequest request, T content)    
 at Microsoft.Workflow.Client.WorkflowManager.StartInternal(String workflowName, WorkflowStartParameters startParameters)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServices.FabricWorkflowManagementClient.StartInstance(String serviceGroupName, String workflowName, String monitoringParam, String activationKey, IDictionary`2 payload)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServices.FabricWorkflowInstanceProvider.StartWorkflow(WorkflowSubscription subscription, IDictionary`2 payload) StackTrace: 
 at Microsoft.Office.Server.Native.dll: (sig=a1000fac-02c7-4003-8d43-320bb54966b7|2|microsoft.office.server.native.pdb, offset=131D6)
 at Microsoft.Office.Server.Native.dll: (offset=21B79)
```

I have attempted the following to try and resolve the issue:

1. Restarted the Service Bus Gateway and the Service Bus Message Broker
   services according to this [link](https://blog.houratious.com/2014/05/sharepoint-2013-workflow-something-went.html).
2. Restarted User Profile Service and User Profile Synchronization
   Service from SharePoint's Central Administration.
3. Validated that the user profile synchronization was still working.
4. Restarted Workflow Manager Website in IIS
5. Restarted Workflow Manager backend service in the Services console.
6. Restarted the server

I'd appreciate any suggestions that anyone has had to resolve this issue.